# Is there a function to stop a JWPlayer (8.7.3) ad and/or ad pod?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

JWPlayer (version 8.7.3+commercial) provides the methods `playAd` and `pauseAd`. But it does NOT provide something to stop an ad and to resume the stream or the VoD.

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#jwplayerplayadtag

There is an answered question from 2014/15, but it does not work for JWPlayer 8 anymore:
[Stop JWPlayer ad playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202139/stop-jwplayer-ad-playback)

For context:

During a livestream we want to show some midrolls and let the JWPlayer request a VAST-URL.
The VAST-URL might return multiple ads within one ad pod.
Now we get an event that something interesting happens within the livestream and we want to stop the ads.
If it is impossible to stop the current ad, we want at least not start the next one within the pod.

We shudder away from destroying and recreating the player just to enable this feature.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: How about calling .setup with an empty list of videos?

Comment: That stops the ad, but it does not resume the underlying video, because browsers block non user initiated video playing.

`jwplayer().setup({file: "/my/great/livestream"})`

But it is definitly one way to do it, with a little challenge for the UX. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As of Version 8.10.1 there seems to be the `skipAd` method. It skips the Ad. `jwplayer().skipAd()`

Answer for 8.7.3:
There is no API for stopping ads.
We got an answer from jwplayer about this (specifically for version 8.7.3):

> Your method of destroying a player therefore recreating a new one is
>   probably the solution you would be opting for as of now.
>
> Due to a potential ability to involve risks as well as fraud, we have
>   limited the ability to stop ads in the past.

Answer (score -1):

`jwplayer().playAd()` will error but will stop the ad. You can follow that up with a `jwplayer().pause(); jwplayer().play();` to return smoothly to the stream.